# How do I use Django's update view to check if email is unique?

Tags: django

```
class UpdateProfile(UpdateView):
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email']
    template_name = 'account/update.html'
    success_url = '/accounts/profile/'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(username=username).count() > 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'This email address is already registered.')
        return email
```

I have the following code above. How do I use UpdateView to check if the email field is unique. If the user added an email that is the same as someone else, I want to add that to form.errors array and prevent the form from saving. What should I do? I tried everything.

Comment: Are you using a custom User model? If you are, you should probably add `unique=True` in your `email` field. If you are not, you should probably use a model form and use it in the view.

Answer (score 1):

In your models.py

```
UserModel(models.Model):
    ...
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    ...
```

This will ensure that you don't have to write any logic on your view to ensure uniqueness of a field.